# Need url of Invalid RSS feed

Tags: parsing, rss

Can anybody provide me the url of invalid RSS feed which can throw a below on of the error:
http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/

Kindly help out. I need to test one functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validating this url: http://httpbin.org/xml will result in [UndefinedElement](http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/error/UndefinedElement.html) error. Or you could take [any rss feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/26860963) and add some errors to the markup and past that into the validator.